last optional argument is not allowed in "\fp_compare" command
while compiling, such an error appears : "! Use of ??? doesn't match its definition. ! LaTeX Error: Erroneous variable \xparse function is not e...".
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\xif}{mmm}{%
 \fp_compare:nTF {#1}{#2}{#3}
}

\NewDocumentCommand\usefpvar{m O{15}}{\fpeval{round(#1, #2)}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


\usefpvar{pi}

\usefpvar{pi}[3]


\xif{ \usefpvar{pi}[3] < 3 } {F} {T} %  ! LaTeX Error: 


\end{document}











You have to use expandable commands inside float expresions

@JosephWright   expandable commands fails \NewExpandableDocumentCommand\usefpvar{m O{15}}{\fpeval{round(#1, #2)}}  . ! LaTeX cmd Error: Bad argument specification 'mO{15}' for \usefpvar.

You can't have an optional argument last in an expandable command

if I don't use \fp_compare , I can have an optional argument last in an command.

Yes: because then you do not need expandable behaviour. We cannot have optional arguments found by expansion, and expressions require expansion. Thats how it is.

What you want cannot be implemented because of certain limitations of TeX engine. Another alternative is to use functional package, where everything is not expandable but it looks like it is — usually the user don't really notice something goes wrong.

thanks. I would use expansion form when meet fp_compare .

Reading the documentation might prove useful.
You need expandable commands. But a command with optional arguments can only be expandable if the last argument is mandatory.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\xif}{mmm}
 {
  \fp_compare:nTF {#1}{#2}{#3}
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\usefpvar{O{15}m}{\fpeval{round(#2, #1)}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\usefpvar{pi}

\usefpvar[3]{pi}

\xif{ \usefpvar[3]{pi} < 3 } {F} {T}

\end{document}


Footnote. I didn't get these notions by some divine grace, but by carefully studying code and documentation. And what I wrote above can easily be found. Thus the downvote to your question remains.

Yes, I've read it. I found numerica package  have optional argument in last position.  that command is \eval{ }[ ]

'reveal useful' -> 'reveal useful information'? or 'be useful'?

@cfr Better, now?

@xcn What has that package to do with the problem at hand? Nothing at all. As far as I remember, very few commands of that package are expandable…

Not much connection. To make a command like that , I define two commands: one is non-expand but with an optional argument last , the other is expandable for expressions that require expansion.

you can't say 'reveal to be useful' in English. you can 'reveal useful insights'. maybe you want 'prove useful'?

Saying anything “can easily be found” regarding TeX/LaTeX documentation is laughable even on the best of days for general users. Your comment is rude and bordering on bullying. Set a better example and stop being arrogant.

@LaTeXereXeTaL texdoc usrguide and look for \NewExpandableDocumentCommand. Is this difficult?
